# How to calculate the current millisecond provided if there is old millisecond in java

Tags: java, android, chronometer

I making a timer in my android app. I have a scenario where I dont need to stop the timer even if the app is closed. If the timer is running and user closes the app and reopen it after sometime. He should see the latest time on the timer. But currently I am not able to show the latest time. I am only able to show the time when the user killed the app. I am storing the time of the timer and when the user open the app I am putting the stored time back to the timer. But I want to show the latest time. Here what I have done till now. I am using chronometer widget.

MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    Chronometer tvTextView;
    Button btnStart, btnStop;
    private int state = 0; //0 means stop state,1 means play, 2 means pause

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private boolean running = false;
    private long pauseOffSet = -1;

    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvTextView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.puzzleProgressBar);

        btnStart = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnStop = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(this);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        state = sharedPreferences.getInt("state", 0);

        tvTextView.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
                long time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
                pauseOffSet=time;
                Log.e(TAG,"pauseOffSet "+pauseOffSet);
                if (time >= 79200000) {
                    tvTextView.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    tvTextView.stop();
                    running = false;
                    progressBar.setProgress(0);
                } else {
                    chronometer.setText(setFormat(time));
                    int convertTime = (int) time;
                    progressBar.setProgress(convertTime);
                }
            }
        });

        if (state == 1) { // its in play mode
            running = true;
            tvTextView.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - sharedPreferences.getLong("milli", 0));
            tvTextView.start();
        } else if (state == 2) { //its in pause mode
            running = false;
            pauseOffSet = sharedPreferences.getLong("milli", -1);
            long time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - pauseOffSet;
            tvTextView.setBase(time);
            int convertTime = (int) pauseOffSet;
            progressBar.setProgress(convertTime);
        } else {
            running = false;
            tvTextView.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (btnStart == v) {
            if (!running) {
                if (pauseOffSet != -1) {
                    pauseOffSet = sharedPreferences.getLong("milli", -1);
                }
                tvTextView.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - pauseOffSet);
                tvTextView.start();
                state = 1;
                pauseOffSet = 0;
                running = true;
            }
        } else if (btnStop == v) {
            if (running) {
                tvTextView.stop();
                pauseOffSet = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - tvTextView.getBase();
                state = 2;
                running = false;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        sharedPreferences.edit().putLong("milli", pauseOffSet).commit();
        sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("state", state).commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy called, state: " + state);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    String setFormat(long time) {
        int h = (int) (time / 3600000);
        int m = (int) (time - h * 3600000) / 60000;
        int s = (int) (time - h * 3600000 - m * 60000) / 1000;
        String hh = h < 10 ? "0" + h : h + "";
        String mm = m < 10 ? "0" + m : m + "";
        String ss = s < 10 ? "0" + s : s + "";
        return hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a Service if you want things to happen in the background.

Comment: I even thought but is it possible to calculate the latest time using the stored time ?

Comment: Yes, and that's simple mathematics, but you should be using a Service.